# Pharo get all setter from a class

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am new in pharo. I have a problem. I want to get all setter from a class in this language. But i don't any idea for do that.
For example, we have ClassA that have a method like:

```
Object SubClass: #ClassA
    instanceVariableNames: 'name age'
    classVariableNames: ''
    package: 'MyPackage'
```

```
name:aName
    name:= aName
```

```
age:anAge
    age:= anAge
```

and i have a protocol setters.

How to get the two setters methods in other class?

Comment: I don't understand how the method signature you provided relates to "two setters methods in other class". Also, do you want to know how to find methods using code or the GUI?

Comment: I just want to get all the setters of a class. I don't know if there is a method in pharo that can achieve this.

Comment: I found a method in pharo which returns all local selectors in a class.       For exemple, Person localSelectors give all the selectors in class Person.that's not bad. but what I want is to get only the setters to instantiate a class for example.

Comment: What is a "setter"? How do you define a "setter"? What do you mean by "get"? Are you asking how to find methods using the GUI? Or using code?

Comment: setters are methods used to modify the private properties of an object.
I would like to know how to access its methods using the source code.

Comment: "I would like to know how to access its methods using the source code." – And how do you define what is and is not a setter? How do you distinguish a method that is a setter from a method that is not a setter? For example, if you say "any method that takes exactly one argument is a setter", then `+` is a setter. If you say "any method that takes exactly one argument and is not a binary operator is a setter", then `ifTrue:` is a setter. If you want a list of all setters, then you need a criterion to figure out what is a setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is what do you mean by "getting"

If you want to have setters/getters for a Class you need to create them.  For example, if you have a Class `Person` then you would need to create setter `#age:` and getter `#age`.

If you want to see all the accessors available for the class you need to check the protocol of the class.  The `accessing` is the protocol where you can find messages which enable you to access the inner values of the object.

If you want to list all the messages available in some protocol you can use (@Pharo 10):

```
| selectors |
selectors := OrderedCollection allSelectorsInProtocol: #'accessing'.
```

Which will give you the following result:

```
a Set(#yourself #enclosedElement #atPin: #before: #first:
#lastIndexOf:startingAt:ifAbsent: #fourth #replaceAll:with: #basicSize
#allButFirst #at:ifAbsent: #atLast: #allButFirst: #lastIndexOf: #size
#indexOfAnyOf:startingAt: #ninth #before:ifAbsent: #at:put: #last
#after:ifAbsent: #basicAt:put: #at: #indexOf:ifAbsent: #atLast:put:
#indexOfAnyOf: #atAll: #replaceFrom:to:with:startingAt: #nextToLast
#replaceFrom:to:with: #middle #first #fifth #at:incrementBy:
#lastIndexOf:ifAbsent: #allButLast: #indexOfSubCollection:startingAt: #atAllPut:
#indexOf:startingAt: #basicAt: #identityIndexOf: #atAll:putAll: #third #indexOf:
#atLast:ifAbsent: #last: #after: #capacity #anyOne #seventh #allButLast
#lastIndexOfAnyOf:startingAt:ifAbsent: #sixth #second #eighth #atAll:put:
#from:to:put: #indexOfAnyOf:ifAbsent: #atWrap:put:
#indexOfAnyOf:startingAt:ifAbsent: #indexOf:startingAt:ifAbsent: #swap:with:
#identityIndexOf:ifAbsent: #atWrap: #indexOfSubCollection:startingAt:ifAbsent:)
```

Comment: ok i will try by listing the methods in the accessing protocol. thank you very much. I'll get back to you if it works.

Comment: Hi @tukan, once I have the list of methods in a well-defined protocol, how can I use it?

Comment: @MansourFaouziel that depends on what you want to do. That you should usually know before getting such list.

Comment: Hi @tukan!in my case, I am looking to retrieve the methods in the accessing protocol of a given class because I would like from a collection containing values to access the private properties of an object in order to be able to instantiate it with these values.

Comment: @MansourFaouziel This is not the way you want to do it.  You want to create class method (which is a constractor) and within it #initialize the values of the object via the instance variables.  I recommend reading beginners book about Smalltalk e.g. http://www.esug.org/data/Lectures/Smalltalk-Lectures.pdf

Comment: I addition to the PDF tukan suggested, I'd point to Stephane Ducasse's extensive collection of (perfectly legal!) PDFs at http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks.html which includes the foundational Blue Book and the highly readable 'A Taste of Smalltalk '